# como darle formato de miles a un input de html

Tags: php, javascript, html, jquery

tengo un input de tipo text el cual trae unos datos numéricos de la base de datos, lo que quiero es poder darle un formato en el cual se coloque puntos de mil, ya que no es un campo donde se inserte los números si no que ya vienen desde la base de datos.
alguien que pueda ayudarme muchas gracias

Answer (score 0):

Puedes utilizar `number_format`
Debes colocar
El valor
La cantidad de decimales
El separador de decimales
El separador de miles

```
$number =1550.6734;
echo number_format($number, 2, ".", ",");

// 1,550.67
```